# Fatal Error C1047

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

I received a project built in VS15 in Release mode. I am trying to build it on my machine that has VS17. The problem is I am receiving this error:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173554.aspx

"The object or library file "pathToFile\file.lib" was created with an older compiler other other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries."

I have tried a Clean and Rebuild here in Visual Studio, tried deleting the .lib file and Cleaning and Building, and even set Link Time Code Generation to "No" in the Librarian section of the project in question's Librarian properties.

I have done some research and checked all possibilities and seems that these are the ones people have recommended. Unfortunately, none have worked, so I am wondering if there's another I am missing?